# Reading lines backwards in bash unix

Tags: bash, file, unix

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
abcdefghijklmn - [description]    
abcdefg - [description]    
efgkhtsf - [description]    
  .   
  .    
  .
```

The list goes on, I need to write a script that reverses each line of the file so that I will have something like this:

```
[noitorecesd] - nmljkihgfedcba         
  .    
  .    
  .
```

Is there a way of doing this? The `[description]`is the same for every line, they could be treated as the same characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rev` is the tool. `man rev` says --> `reverse lines of a file or files`:

```
$ rev file
]noitpircsed[ - nmlkjihgfedcba
]noitpircsed[ - gfedcba
]noitpircsed[ - fsthkgfe
```

To have the brackets shown properly, replace `[` with `]` and the other way round:

```
$ rev file | sed -e 's/\[/XXX/g' -e 's/\]/[/g' -e 's/XXX/\]/g'
[noitpircsed] - nmlkjihgfedcba
[noitpircsed] - gfedcba
[noitpircsed] - fsthkgfe
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `tr` and `rev`:

```
tr '][' '[]' < inputfile | rev
```

This doesn't require one to find characters in the input that do not exist in order to interchange `[` and `]`.

For your sample input, it'd result in:

```
[noitpircsed] - nmlkjihgfedcba
[noitpircsed] - gfedcba
[noitpircsed] - fsthkgfe
```

Comment: This `tr` is pretty cool, way better than using `sed` as I did.

Comment: @fedorqui `tr` is one of those little known utilities that are very handy at times.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Can I follow up on one more question? say if I have a file and I want to delete the first 5 characters of every line, how should I go about doing that?

Comment: @user3351901 `cut -c6- < inputfile`